# Exit From MMDrawerController Left View Controler

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am using `MMDrawerController`. I used `TableView` in `LeftViewController` to display my data in Custom Cells.

`LeftViewController` slides out from left when i click the bar button.

i want to redirect to other `ViewControler` from `LeftViewController` after clicking on custom cell of my `TableView`.

in my `LeftViewController` i am using the below code

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CenterViewController" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ViewController *VC = (ViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];

}
```

Note: `CenterViewController` is the `Storyboard` ID of `ViewController`

by using the above code, `ViewController` appears on top of `LeftViewController` but i want to close `LeftViewController` and redirect to `ViewController`

[image: My Storyboard]

i used the below code, Although it works but then swipe left and right does not work on `ViewController`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController *ggg = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
        UINavigationController *navcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ggg];
    AppDelegate *app =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.window.rootViewController = navcon;
    [app.drawerController toggleDrawerSide:MMDrawerSideLeft animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have the following options:

1. Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` in `CenterViewController` and assign the `CenterViewController` instance as the delegate of the `UITableView` in `LeftViewController`.
2. Create a *delegate* for `LeftViewController` so you can keep your `UITableViewDelegate`'s logic in `LeftViewController` and implement the new delegate in `CenterViewController` and assign it as delegate of `LeftViewController`.
3. Use `NSNotificationCenter` to post a notification when the user selects an item in `LeftViewController`'s `UITableView` and add `CenterViewController` as an observer of the notification.

**Update 1**

HI, In the code I see you are assigning a new rootViewController probably replacing the instance of MMDrawerController with your own ViewControler and because of that you loose the swipe gesture.

Maybe the only thing you need is to assign the center controller to MMDrawerController calling `setCenterViewController:`

instead of

```
app.window.rootViewController = navcon;
```

use

```
[drawerControllerInstance setCenterViewController:navcon];
```

Comment: i tried the didSelectRowAtIndexPath as edit in my question although it works but then swipe left and right does not work on ViewController